# Pass parameters to sql agent job Transact-SQL Script (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

We have 10 databases (1 per location) and 1 master database on the warehouse server. These 10 databases correlate to their OLTP counterpart on another server.  I created a stored procedure in the master database to move data from the source to the destination.

Instead of creating a cursor and looping though all of the databases, I was trying to see if there is a way to pass a parameter into a SQL Server Agent Job for each database – Essentially having 10 SQL Agent Jobs (1 per database)

Is there a way in the Job > Steps > Command Window to declare a variable for the school and have it pass into the replicate stored procedure?

Job 1

```
Declare @Source_DB varchar(max)
        @Target_DB Varchar(max)

Set @Source_DB = ‘School_1’
Set @Target_DB= ‘DW_School_1’

Exec Replicate @Source_DB, @Target_DB
```

Job 2

```
Declare @Source_DB varchar(max)
        @Target_DB Varchar(max)

Set @Source_DB = ‘School_2’
Set @Target_DB= ‘DW_School_2’

Exec Replicate @Source_DB, @Target_DB
```

Job 3

```
Declare @Source_DB varchar(max)
        @Target_DB Varchar(max)

Set @Source_DB = ‘School_3’
Set @Target_DB= ‘DW_School_3’

Exec Replicate @Source_DB, @Target_DB
```

Job 4…....

Comment: look into the system proc sp_MSforeachdb

Answer (score 0):

something like this using sp_MSforeachdb

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
--SELECT @command = 'USE ? SELECT ''?'' as mainDB, ''DW_?'' as warehouseDB' 
SELECT @command = 'Exec Replicate ?, ''DW_?'''

print @command

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```